# VBA: Getting run-time 1004: Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed

Tags: excel, runtime-error, vba

I am assigning a worksheet to a variable to make it easier to work with.  All other actions I take on this object (compare and writes) work, but I can't get it to put a border around a range.  It gives me the 1004 error for Range method failed.  What am I doing wrong here?

Code in question (the last line is where the debugger triggers):

```
Dim destRow As Range
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim target As Worksheet
    Dim listSize As Long

    listSize = Me.FeatureNumber_ListBox.listCount
    Set target = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("mySheet")
    lastRow = target.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1

    ' put borders around whole row
    target.Range(Cells(lastRow, 1), Cells(lastRow, 19)).Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `target.Cells` not `Cells` because otherwise the `Cells` context isn't necessarily where you want it to be?

Comment: Perfect! That actually makes sense, and is why I placed the worksheet into a short, easy to type variable...  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

corrected code :

```
with target

    lastRow = .Cells( .Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1  'added 2 dots (".")

    ' put borders around whole row
    .Range( .Cells(lastRow, 1), .Cells(lastRow, 19)).Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous  ' Added 3 Dots (".")

    '...
End With
```